# Download And Install (Jetbrains products) IntellijIdea-webStorm-phpStorm idea 32 bit Linux tar.gz

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, installation, 32-bit

i have trouble finding the right version for my OS.
it seems that after 2018 there is no support for 32 bit in newer versions
Jetbrains download version only provides the last 3 releases
it there a way to download older versions ?
please help !

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html.

Comment: yeah i was that, i tough the page only contains the last version. did'nt know i can scroll to the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can the last version but ones **with JR8 Bundled**
in jetbrains download page, below the main version download area
here is the picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnpre.png

but if you really want to download older versions use this

```
https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2018.3.6.tar.gz?_ga=2.47016871.1424988563.1577291372-1484722978.1577291372
```

**you can change the version**

**you can change the app name (to webstorm,phpstorm or else)**

**you can change the type of the file (to .exe or else)**